# ipaddr.js thinks any number is an IP address

Tags: typescript, ip, ip-address

I'm wanting to return true if the string being passed into the function is an IP address.

function looks a bit like this

```
import * as ipaddr from 'ipaddr.js';

function isIpaddress(ip) {

return ipaddr.isValid(ip);
}
```

This returns true for any number being passed into it? Anyone know why this happens as a first time user of ipaddr.js, i would have thought .isValid would perform all the necessary checks?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Copy of stackblitz here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-console-log-template-d2vdm4?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Any valid unsigned 32-bit integer is a valid IPv4 address.

```
> Buffer.from([192, 168, 0, 1])
<Buffer c0 a8 00 01>
> Buffer.from([192, 168, 0, 1]).readUInt32BE(0)
3232235521
> require('ipaddr.js').parse('3232235521')
IPv4 { octets: [ 192, 168, 0, 1 ] }
> require('ipaddr.js').parse('99999999999') // not uint32
Uncaught Error: ipaddr: the address has neither IPv6 nor IPv4 format
```